# how to get the workflow id from github from a specific branch

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to call github api to list out the workflow id

```
response_workflow = requests.get(
    f"{github_api_name}/actions/workflows",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {github_token}", "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json"}
)
```

But it is always showing the workflow id of main branch.
Is there anyway to get the workflow id which a workflow dispatch from a specific branch?